# How to success to click a tag with javascript using Selenium lib?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a problem with selenium ....

I want to success to click a tag with javascript.

copy path is

```
//*[@id="divList"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a
```

So I coded like this:

```
device_id_list=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divList\"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"));
device_id_list.click();
```

but it doesn't work!!

Error is here

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
> no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="divList"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkRks.jpg)/a"}
> (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)

Before click(); I think my code can't get element using by.xpath.

I don't know why it doesn't work. I need help!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkRks.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="txt_l">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="fnDetail('00000417702c1ffffe5bdedf')">00000417702c1ffffe5bdedf</a> 
</td>
<td>  . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

try belo code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='txt_l']//a"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
WebElement element =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), '00000417702c1ffffe5bdedf')]")));
element.click();
```

Comment: I found why it doesn't work! That html source is source after I clicked search button. So It takes time . Previously, I set Thread.sleep(1000) . But after I changed '3000' , it work corrently !

Comment: Great!! To avoid synchronization issue use WebDriverWait instead of Thread.sleep(1000)